# order confirmation email not sent in magento CE 2.4.5-p1 when placed on Front-End

Tags: magento2, email, order-email, magento2.4.5

But, order confirmation email is sent when placed on Back-End.
Note: all other emails are sent as expected (processing, updates, etc..)

Comment: Any Exception or Error in log files??

Comment: Kindly review the system.log or exception.log files. Proceed to initiate the order confirmation email from the sale->order section. Open any order and activate the "send email" button. Afterward, inspect the logs for the latest error message.